# What are the other .onion like top-level domains supported by Tor?

Tags: onion-routing, tor-browser-bundle

I've found this [page](https://www.deepdotweb.com/questions/question/how-to-open-clos-loky-domain-url-in-dw/) where user asks how to open `.clos` and `.loky` domains. I assume these aren't the valid domain suffixes.

However to avoid confusion, my question is, which the hidden top-level domains suffixes are exactly supported by Tor browser (ignoring surface web one) other than `.onion`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [.tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tor)

> .tor is a pseudo-top-level domain host suffix implemented by the OnioNS project, which aims to add DNS infrastructure to the Tor network enabling the selection of meaningful and globally-unique domain name for hidden services, which users can then reference from the Tor Browser.

## [.exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion#.exit)

> .exit is a pseudo-top-level domain used by Tor users to indicate on the fly to the Tor software the preferred exit node that should be used while connecting to a service such as a web server, without having to edit the configuration file for Tor (torrc).

Answer (score 0):

First, dot-tor are **not** supported by Tor itself - it's a side product, don't mess things up! dot-exit is a Tor's feature to map exits, and dot-onion is the *only* top-level suffix to address a Tor darknet hidden services

Comment: "Don't mess things up!"? This is a question-and-answer site, check the attitude at the door.

Comment: @T.J.L. I mean that speaking of something supposed to be related to Tor must not include the things that are *designed to deceive* the fact of it's relation to Tor. It's **defenately not a bad language** - it's a warning not to buy on theese "tor extensions" designed to wiretap. I've mentioned the *only* things "supported by" *and* "directly related to" Tor, and not to say "RTFM, dude" or anything like that. I used to help a person on Tor.SE - and via TeamViewer I saw a **fake TBB bundle with a side binary instead of tor.exe** - it's even mimic'ed it's output *and reported errors in torrc*

Comment: That is all useful information that could be part of an answer. Instead, what you've written reads as rather elitist - I didn't say anything about bad language, I was objecting to the attitude and tone of the statement.

Comment: @T.J.L. It is a loud warning, like one we all need at out early childhood when we're about to play with a power outlet : it **is** dangerous.